# May immersion cooling cause components to crack?

Tags: cooling

Just wondering if a component that has Moisture Sensitivity Level greater than 1 may also absorb ethanol or other coolant liquid used for immersion cooling and then crack when its boiling temperature reached. PCBs with its porous structure worry me even more.

Comment: "Moisture Sensitivity Level greater than 1"... On what scale of what units?

Comment: @KingDuken https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moisture_sensitivity_level

Comment: @BeB00 _(slaps forehead)_ Oh I see haha. I thought that was some arbitrary statement.